# What is the class of method references?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, method-reference

I have the following code:

```
List<Person> personList = getPersons();    
List<Function<List<Person>, Stream<Person>>> streams = new ArrayList<>();
streams.add(p -> p.stream());
streams.add(p -> p.parallelStream());
```

Intellij Idea suggests I should replace the lambda expressions to method references.
I'd like to do so, only I'm not sure what should be the new generic type of the streams list.
I tried to evaluate the expression personList::stream but I get "No such instance field: 'stream'". If I try List::stream or ArrayList::stream (The concrete type of the person list) I get: "No such static field: 'stream'".
Is there a way to add method references to a list?
if so what should be the list's generic type?

Thanks

As assylias pointed out, IDEA was just complaining and the code ran without problem,
I still had problems with the same code in IDEA 13 since streams.add expected a function that returns Stream and List::stream returns Stream. To solve it I ended up using the following code:

```
List<Person> personList = getPersons();
List<Supplier<Stream<Person>>> streams = new ArrayList<>();
streams.add(personList::stream);
streams.add(personList::parallelStream);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compiles fine (b119):

```
List<String> personList = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
List<Function<List<String>, Stream<String>>> streams = new ArrayList<>();
streams.add(List::stream);
streams.add(List::parallelStream);
```

You may be using an old build of the jdk or IntelliJ is messing with you!

Comment: Thanks, I am using b124, and IDEA 12.1.6. As you said, IDEA just complains but this code runs fine.

Comment: I saw the same problem in IDA 13.1.6. That same line of code in the debugger's "Code Fragment Mode" gives a bogus "No such static method" error; even though the code runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

`personList::stream` is basically the same as `p -> p.stream()`. Neither has a type per se. The type of the expression is the type of the context that accepts it.